# Using slash instead of apostrophe

Tags: punctuation, literature

I'm reading the novel [Requiem for a Dream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Requiem_for_a_Dream_(novel)) by Selby Jr. It has some strange grammar for common contractions. For example instead of "we're" it is "we/re", "I'll" it is "Ill" and "we'd" it is "we/d" and in some places the author commits where the apostrophe completely. Was this normal or some alternative use? Or is this some sort of mistake? Is it supposed to represent the accent in New York?

Comment: How are you reading it? Is it an ebook, where odd formatting of punctuation might represent an encoding error?

Comment: @sumelic Probably not, it can be seen in [Amazon's ebook preview](https://www.amazon.com/Requiem-Dream-Hubert-Selby-Jr-ebook/dp/B006D23DBW) and [Google's preview](https://books.google.com/books?id=E2U-UTULr6cC&q="we%20re").

Comment: @sumelic printed paper back

Comment: I think this question may be better suited for our [Literature site](https://literature.stackexchange.com/tour). If other people agree, then we can ask a moderator to move the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a quirk of the author (and not the only one either). According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubert_Selby_Jr.):

> Little concerned with proper grammar, punctuation, or diction, Selby used unorthodox techniques in most of his works. He indented his paragraphs with alternating lengths, often by simply dropping down one line when finished with a paragraph. Like Jack Kerouac in his "spontaneous prose", Selby often completed his writing in a fast, stream-of-consciousness style. **He replaced apostrophes with forward slashes "/," which were closer on the typewriter, to avoid interrupting his flow of writing.** He did not use quotation marks. He might present a dialogue as a complete paragraph, with no denotion among alternating speakers. His prose was stripped down, bare and blunt.

Specifically, on its page for the 2005 documentary, *Hubert Selby Jr: It/ll Be Better Tomorrow*, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubert_Selby_Jr:_It/ll_Be_Better_Tomorrow) says:

> In the film, Selby explains that, on his manual typewriter, an apostrophe meant typing an "uppercase 8", so it was simpler to use a slash.

So, you'll see slashes throughout his work. For example, this excerpt from [Waiting Period](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0714530905):

> But suppose I suddenly change my mind and call 911? What happens then? **I/d** end up in a funny farm with millions of people asking me questions, driving me nuts wanting to know why I did it, as if living in this world is so wonderful you must be crazy to want to leave it.

Comment: Out of curiosity did the author intentionally do this or did he just have bad grammar?

Comment: @northerner See the second quote. He did it on purpose because it was simpler. I think they were left in because of "style", since, if they were indeed unintentional, then the editors would have fixed it.

Comment: @northener He did it intentionally **and** he punctuated badly.